# Line parallel to plane

Tags: linear-algebra, analytic-geometry

See if the line e is parallel with to the plane $α$. If not, find the intersecting point. 
$$\begin{align} α: & \quad \quad x-3y+z+1=0 \\ e: & \quad \{x+y-z=3, 2x-y-4z=3\} \end{align}$$

Comment: how to make line e into a single equation?

Comment: I believe you meant equal instead of a minus for the line $e$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a line is parallel to the plane, consider the consequences: any vectors that are orthogonal to the plane must be orthogonal to the line. This turns out to be the condition we need to check.

To find the line, work with the system of equations as to single out a variable. Added both equations we get $3x-5z=6$ or $x = 2 + (5z)/3$. Using the first equation we can write $$y=3+z-x = 3+z-2-\frac{5z}{3} = 1 - \frac{2z}{3}.$$ The line is now parameterized by $z$ as $$\begin{align} x & = 2 + \frac{5z}{3}, \\ y & = 1 - \frac{2z}{3}, \\ z & = z. \end{align}$$

To finish, you need to take two points in the line, translate that into a vector with initial and end point as chosen and check if it's orthogonal to the orthogonal vector to the plane, found using the coefficients of the given equation.

Comment: Downvoter: care to explain?

Comment: thanks a lot got the right answer. The plane and the line are not parallel and the intersection point is (2,1,0)

Comment: Glad this has helped. =)

Comment: why are there downvotes here?

Comment: @Fantini - nice and clear answer - there should be no downvote! Voteup!

Comment: @johannesvalks Thank you, that is very kind!

Comment: @Fantini - you deserved the upvote and I don't understand why people downvote without a remark to explain the downvote...

Comment: @johannesvalks Me neither, but it happens every now and then.